# xDebug not stopping at breakpoint

Tags: php, linux, visual-studio, xdebug, centos6

I've been searching in google and stackoverflow for hours.....didn't find a reason...

I have my app hosted in a Centos 6.5 Apache and debugging from my dev machine with Visual Studio + PHP Tools.

It was working prefectly fine until I did some update, restart, couchdb install/configuration (and a lot of other things) to the Centos machine, then I notice the xdebug doesn't stop at breakpoint anymore, it only stops if there is exception or I write out xdebug_break() in the PHP script...

I tried disable SELinux, Iptables, it doesn't help as well.

Then I looked at the xdebug.log file, it gives me random error as follows:

```
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/ec2-user/webapps/webapps/PVPCardGame/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="$

<- breakpoint_set -i x0-10000 -t exception -x "Fatal error"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="x0-10000" id="39890001"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i x1-10001 -t exception -x "Parse error"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="x1-10001" id="39890002"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i x2-10002 -t exception -x "Unknown error"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="x2-10002" id="39890003"></response>

<- feature_get -i 3 -n max_children
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="3" feature_name="max_children" supported="1"><![CDATA[32]]></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 4-0 -t line -f file:///home/ec2-user/webapps/webapps/PVPCardGame_fuel/app/classes/controller/user.php -n 104
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4-0" id="39890004"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 5-1 -t line -f file:///home/ec2-user/webapps/webapps/PVPCardGame_fuel/app/classes/controller/user.php -n 108
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5-1" id="39890005"></response>
```

So it does connected to my client, but I have zero idea from what error log...

XDebug Version  2.3.2
PHP Version 5.4.41

Answer (score 0):

I've uninstalled PHP 5.4.41 from my Linux machine and reinstalled into PHP 5.5.27 which is higher version.
And all of the sudden is working.

I believe is because how xDebug works, it runs on Linux's PHP and sending debug information to my local machine, which is interpreted in different version of PHP 5.6.8.... That's why is not working.